# Make output pdf files binary identical

Tags: pdf, matplotlib, pdf-generation, diff

I'm using Matplotlib to produce a large batch of plots (order of thousands). I'll frequently tweak minor things in the code that produces the plots, but the changes will often only affect a few plots.

When I push new plots to a common repository, I'd like to use something like `rsync` or `diff` to identify which plots have actually changed. Unfortunately, running `diff new_plot.pdf old_plot.pdf` *always* identifies the files as different, even if *nothing* about the plotting script has changed.

When I output to `.png` the files are identical. When I output to an `.eps` the output is nearly identical, but running diff shows that a few lines have been swapped. I suspect there are two reasons for the difference:

1. A pdf stores metadata, including a time-stamp.
2. Some vector graphics may look identical even without the same description (i.e. a line could be drawn from right to left or from left to right). I'd expect matplotlib to be deterministic, but it clearly does things slightly differently in the `.eps` instance, so I guess not.

Is there some way to turn off `.pdf` metadata, and either force a more deterministic drawing method out of matplotlib or feed the files to a diff tool that sees them as identical?

Comment: what are you using to get the matplotlib figure to pdf?

Comment: @Joop, I'm using something like `FigureCanvasAgg(figure).print_figure(name)` (although in more complicated scripts that may be broken into a few more lines)

Answer (score 1):

This [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multipage_pdf.html) contains how to set your creation and modification dates using [PdfPages](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_pdf_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages).
I've tried the code and executed `diff` without any difference between my pdf figures.

PS: those last two lines effect the differences in your files, so try to attach them with fixed values you want:

```
d['CreationDate'] = datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 13)
d['ModDate'] = datetime.datetime.today()
```

to

```
d['CreationDate'] = datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 6)
d['ModDate'] = datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 6)
```